# Opening a socket over a RS232 connection

Tags: .net, sockets

I have a 'C# server' program listening to '127.0.0.1', port 5500, using .NET socket, and i have a corresponding C# client program sending messages to this socket from the same PC. They both work fine.

Now if i run the 'client' and 'server' programs on seperate PC's and connect them via a cable connecting their serial ports (RS232), should i make changes to code to make them work ? I am asking since i dont have 2 PC's to check , but need it to work when deployed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if both computers have appropriate drivers to treat the serial port *as* a network connection, it should work without any changes.

Otherwise, you'll have to use the [`SerialPort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) class. to explicitly talk over the serial port.

You may find it best to abstract your code so that it works over *streams* - then you can get the stream from a network connection *or* a serial connection, and most of your code won't need to change.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is bound to 127.0.0.1 then yes, you need to set it to 0.0.0.0

The reason is that if a socket is bound to an IP address, it will only accept requests on that IP address. 127.0.0.1 is only used as a machines IP address if the originator is on the same machine (it's a separate network interface, set up as a loopback). 0.0.0.0 means 'any IP address', so you can open a socket that will accept incoming connections from any network interface on the machine.

As for running it over a serial cable... no idea if that will work or not, and most likely requires a lot of setup to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're in for a lot of pain if you continue down this path :-)

TCP/IP *generally* works over ethernet - I've never seen a driver that would run the physical layer on RS232 serial ports although it's by no means impossible.

You'd be better off connecting those two machines using a standard network cable.

Answer (score 0):

TCP/IP also works over SLIP.  Remember that old way you used to connect to the internet?  PPP would work as well.  But I don't think that that's what he's looking for.

Comment: TCP/IP with Stream abstraction , as Jon Skeet said is what i am working with now. Am testing - OK so far.