# Using a USB-to-USB cable bridge to communicate information between two computers

Tags: c#, windows, usb, communication, libusbdotnet

I am wondering if it is possible for me to use a USB-to-USB cable bridge to establish a communication link between my applications on two different computers.

Currently I have an application which runs embedded on an industrial Linux computer and I have a configuration application which runs on a user's laptop and the configuration application discovers and connects to the embedded application over the local network.

I am trying to determine if I am able to use a USB link to communicate between the two applications instead of using the local network.

I know direct USB-to-USB does not work by design, but I am aware of USB-to-USB bridge cables which can be used to for example transfer files between two directly connected computers.

Is there a way for me to programmatically leverage such a cable (specifically in C#) in a way that allows me to have the same communication capabilities I have over a local network socket?

I am aware of libraries like LibUsbDotNet, but they don't seem to provide the capabilities I am describing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Really depends on what the USB->USB device enumerates as...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PC to PC USB communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317823/pc-to-pc-usb-communication)

Comment: See also [Opening a socket over a RS232 connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995004/opening-a-socket-over-a-rs232-connection) which might help for the other part of your question.